# Integral Notation of $M= c \rho_0 \int_{0}^{a}\ \mathsf dx\ \left(1+\frac{x}{a} \right)\left(\frac{bx^2}{2a^2}-\frac{bx}{a}+\frac{b}{2}\right)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was asked to evaluate the integral $$M= c \rho_0 \int_{0}^{a}\ \mathsf dx\  \left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\left(\frac{bx^2}{2a^2}-\frac{bx}{a}+\frac{b}{2}\right).$$

Is this the same as evaluating $$M= c \rho_0 \int_{0}^{a}  \left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\left(\frac{bx^2}{2a^2}-\frac{bx}{a}+\frac{b}{2}\right)\ \mathsf dx\quad ?$$

I tried evaluating the latter integral and obtained the result of $-\frac{1}{2}abc \rho_0$, however the answer given states $\frac{5}{24} abc \rho_0$. Is the error in the way the integral is to be set up?

Comment: You can write the dx wherever you want. It is usually at either the front or the back, and it's really just a matter of personal taste which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing some obvious cleaning up (pull out constant factors, substitute $x=au$), $$M=\frac{1}{2}abc\rho_{0} \int_{0}^{1}(1+u)(u^{2}-2u+1)du \\=\frac{1}{2}abc\rho_{0}\int_{0}^{1}(u^{3}-u^{2}-u+1)du \\=\frac{1}{2}abc\rho_{0}(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+1)=\frac{5}{24}abc\rho_{0}$$
You must have made a mistake in the algebra. Where you write the $dx$ does not change the value of the integral.